# can't find the file that webpack production mode generated

Tags: node.js, webpack

The problem is:
If I set the mode to 'production', the js file will not show up in build folder.
But if I set the mode to 'development', the file will show up.

I want to know why production mode is not working.
Here is my config

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'none',
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'client.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
        publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js']
    },
};
```

And node code to build file

```
 webpack(config)
        .run(function (err, stats) {
            console.log(stats.toString({
                chunks: false,
                colors: true
            }));
            console.log('Compiled.')
        })
```

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: What do you mean the js file not show up in the build folder ?

Comment: Solved by change config optimization: {noEmitOnErrors: false};